# How to Ignore 1st line in the notepad using LOAD DATA LOCAL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a creating a code for importing data in the database using txt file. I'm using `LOAD LOCAL DATA` function. It's works fine except the first line save also in the database which I don't want to happen since these indicates the header. How to remove this one?

The first line I mean is the fistname, lastname and the team.

```
Here's my text file
-----------------------------
Firstname Lastname Team 
Stephen   Curry    Warriors
Lebron    James    Cavaliers
Michael   Jordan   Chicago Bulls
```

I'm using this code. .

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE players(fname,lname,team)";
```

Comment: There is a switch for that check tje the manual

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IGNORE  number {LINES | ROWS}]` syntax.

**Documentation**:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```